# how to have a video be shown after a certain date

Tags: django, date, django-models

I made a category in my database called 'show_after_date', which is a DateTimeField, and I want to put in my view that an item will only be rendered to the template if the date today is 'show_after_date' or later.

My models is:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class video (models.Model):

    VID_CHOICES = (
        ('News', 'News'),
        ('Stam', 'Stam'),
        ('Music', 'Music'),
        ('Ad', 'Ad'),
    )
    
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    show_after_time = models.DateTimeField('show after')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=VID_CHOICES)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the 'datetime' module to be able to get the current time, and then I added

```
.filter(show_after_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

to the database query, so now its

```
video_object = video.objects.filter(show_after_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now()).order_by("-show_after_time")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Stack Overflow, it's best to usually attempt to write some code before posting and provide this with specific issues instead of general ideas you are trying to achieve. This is probably why you've been downvoted.

If you provide your views, etc. I could help more but essentially what you're looking to do is take care of this logic in your view. Something like the following:

1. Read items from the model
2. Check the `show_after_Date` against current date
3. Pass objects to template via context